# Python code to invoke SQL Server stored procedure to ingest CSVs takes HOURS to execute

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I'm using python to read CSVs with Pandas, fix a few fields, and then write, row by row the data to a table in SQL Server.  Bulk imports are disabled on the server - also, because eventually there will be dozens of these files, to automate file download and ingestion.  I can see this taking minutes, but it's taking HOURS to run.

I know that I could bulk upload this stuff in a few seconds, if that were enabled, but that may not be possible.

The problem is that using the python can take 1 to 3 hours per run.  This is not acceptable.  I would like to know if there is a quicker way to do this upload.  Is there something I can do with the table to make this quicker to import, or a different way of coding.

Here's an example of the kind of code I'm using:

```
def ingest_glief_reporting_exceptions_csv():
    global conn
    global cursor
    filename = r"20200824-0800-gleif-goldencopy-repex-golden-copy.csv"
    # filename = r"repex_1K.csv"

    full_filename = os.path.join(raw_data_dir, filename)

    sql_str = "exec dbo.util_get_gleif_last_reporting_exception"
    cursor.execute(sql_str)
    last_lei = ''
    for result in cursor.fetchall():
        last_lei = result[0]

    # "repex" is short for "reporting exceptions", shorten the headers
    repex_headers = [
        'LEI',
        'ExceptionCategory',
        'ExceptionReason1',
        'ExceptionReason2',
        'ExceptionReason3',
        'ExceptionReason4',
        'ExceptionReason5',
        'ExceptionReference1',
        'ExceptionReference2',
        'ExceptionReference3',
        'ExceptionReference4',
        'ExceptionReference5'
    ]

    df = pd.read_csv(full_filename, header=0, quotechar='"')

    # Change to the column headers generated in VBA
    df.columns = repex_headers

    for colname in df.columns:
        df[colname] = df[colname].astype(str)
        df[colname] = df[colname].replace({'nan': ''})


    place_holder = '?,?'
    for i in range(1, len(repex_headers)):
        place_holder += ',?'

    sql_str = "exec save_gleif_reporting_exception " + place_holder

    row_count = 0
    row = dict()
    do_not_upload = True
    if last_lei == '':
        do_not_upload = False   # There was no last uploaded record, so we can start now

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        row_count += 1
        if do_not_upload:
            if row['LEI'] == last_lei:
                do_not_upload = False
                continue
            else:
                continue

        values = (
            row['LEI'],
            row['ExceptionCategory'],
            row['ExceptionReason1'],
            row['ExceptionReason2'],
            row['ExceptionReason3'],
            row['ExceptionReason4'],
            row['ExceptionReason5'],
            row['ExceptionReference1'],
            row['ExceptionReference2'],
            row['ExceptionReference3'],
            row['ExceptionReference4'],
            row['ExceptionReference5'],
            filename
        )

        if index % 1000 == 0:
                print("Imported %s rows" % (index))

        # print(values)
        # print("processing row ", row_count)
        # return Key is the unique ID the database generated as it inserted this row of data.
        error_sql_str = "exec log_message ?,?,?,?,?, ?,?,?,?"
        connection_failures = 0
        connection_failing = True
        while connection_failures < 3 and connection_failing:
            try:
                return_key = cursor.execute(sql_str, values).fetchval()
            except pyodbc.OperationalError as e:
                connection_failures += 1
                connection_failing = True
                print("Connection issue.  connection failures = ", connection_failures)
                time.sleep(30)      # wait 30 seconds and go to the top of the loop to try again.
                continue
            except pyodbc.ProgrammingError as e:
                print("Bad field ", values)
                error_values = (
                    'ERROR',
                    __file__,
                    filename,
                    'gleif_reporting_exceptions',
                    row['LEI'],
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    str(e)
                )
                return_key = cursor.execute(error_sql_str, error_values).fetchval()
                connection_failures = 0
            connection_failures = 0
            connection_failing = False

        if connection_failures >= 3:
            print("Unable to reconnect after 3 tries")
            exit(1)

    conn.close()
    return
```

I open the database like so:

```
def init_connection(server_name, db_name):
    """
    Connect to SQL Server database
    :param server_name:
    :param db_name:
    :return:
    """
    pyodbc.pooling = False
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect(
            r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server_name + '; \
            Database=' + db_name + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;', timeout=5, autocommit=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to connect to database [" + db_name + '] and server [' + server_name + ']')
        print(e)
        exit(1)

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    return [conn, cursor]
```

Okay.

The table is defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[gleif_exceptions](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ida_last_update_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [ida_last_update_source_file] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [LEI] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ExceptionCategory] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ExceptionReason1] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ExceptionReason2] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ExceptionReason3] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ExceptionReason4] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ExceptionReason5] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ExceptionReference1] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ExceptionReference2] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ExceptionReference3] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ExceptionReference4] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ExceptionReference5] [nvarchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Here's some sample data:

```
LEI,Exception.Category,Exception.Reason.1,Exception.Reason.2,Exception.Reason.3,Exception.Reason.4,Exception.Reason.5,Exception.Reference.1,Exception.Reference.2,Exception.Reference.3,Exception.Reference.4,Exception.Reference.5
004L5FPTUREIWK9T2N63,DIRECT_ACCOUNTING_CONSOLIDATION_PARENT,NON_CONSOLIDATING,,,,,,,,,
00EHHQ2ZHDCFXJCPCL46,DIRECT_ACCOUNTING_CONSOLIDATION_PARENT,NON_CONSOLIDATING,,,,,,,,,
```

And here is the corresponding stored procedure I invoke to store a record into the table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[save_gleif_reporting_exception]
    @LEI [nvarchar] (500) = NULL,
    @ExceptionCategory [nvarchar] (500) = NULL,
    @ExceptionReason1 [nvarchar] (500) = NULL,
    @ExceptionReason2 [nvarchar] (500) = NULL,
    @ExceptionReason3 [nvarchar] (500) = NULL,
    @ExceptionReason4 [nvarchar] (500) = NULL,
    @ExceptionReason5 [nvarchar] (500) = NULL,
    @ExceptionReference1 [nvarchar] (500) = NULL,
    @ExceptionReference2 [nvarchar] (500) = NULL,
    @ExceptionReference3 [nvarchar] (500) = NULL,
    @ExceptionReference4 [nvarchar] (500) = NULL,
    @ExceptionReference5 [nvarchar] (500) = NULL,
    @ida_last_update_source_file [nvarchar] (500) NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO dbo.gleif_reporting_exceptions(
        [LEI],
        [ExceptionCategory],
        [ExceptionReason1],
        [ExceptionReason2],
        [ExceptionReason3],
        [ExceptionReason4],
        [ExceptionReason5],
        [ExceptionReference1],
        [ExceptionReference2],
        [ExceptionReference3],
        [ExceptionReference4],
        [ExceptionReference5],
        [ida_last_update_date],
        [ida_last_update_source_file]
    )
    VALUES (
        @LEI,
        @ExceptionCategory,
        @ExceptionReason1,
        @ExceptionReason2,
        @ExceptionReason3,
        @ExceptionReason4,
        @ExceptionReason5,
        @ExceptionReference1,
        @ExceptionReference2,
        @ExceptionReference3,
        @ExceptionReference4,
        @ExceptionReference5,
        GETDATE(),
        @ida_last_update_source_file
    
    )

    SELECT @@IDENTITY

END
```

Note 1: although I'm declaring string as nvarchar (500), most of them are not near that long.  I don't think that matters.  I tried with shorter string definitions and it still takes very long to run the routine.

Note 2: This is just one example among 7 so far.  The smallest tables have on the order of a few 10s of K-rows, and as many as a few million.  The number of columns varies between 7 to about 230.

Comment: Your code does not seem to be doing anything with `return_key`. Is it used anywhere else, i.e., do you really need to retrieve it?

Comment: I'm not using it in this case.  I plagiarized the code from other work I had done previously where I was using the return_key.  I can take that out and see if it speeds things up.

Comment: Okay, then are you able to INSERT directly into the table instead of using the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need the return value from the stored procedure you should be able to just use pandas' `to_sql` method to insert the rows directly into the table. This code …

```py
from time import time
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

from_engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://@mssqlLocal64")
to_engine = sa.create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc://sa:_whatever_@192.168.0.199/mydb"
    "?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server",
    fast_executemany=False,
)

# set up test
to_cnxn = to_engine.raw_connection()
to_cnxn.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE MillionRows")
to_cnxn.commit()
num_rows_to_upload = 10000
df = pd.read_sql_query(
    f"SELECT TOP {num_rows_to_upload} "
    "[TextField], [LongIntegerField], [DoubleField], [varchar_column] "
    "FROM MillionRows ORDER BY ID",
    from_engine,
)

# run test
t0 = time()
df.to_sql("MillionRows", to_engine, index=False, if_exists="append")
s = f"{(time() - t0):0.1f} seconds"
print(f"uploading {num_rows_to_upload:,d} rows took {s}")
```

… represents roughly the same internal level of effort as what you are doing now, i.e., uploading each individual row as a separate `.execute` call. The result is

```
uploading 10,000 rows took 60.2 seconds
```

However, simply changing `to_engine` to use `fast_executemany=True` results in

```
uploading 10,000 rows took 1.4 seconds
```

Comment: Sorry.  Being pulled to another effort yesterday and most of today.  I'll look at this hopefully before end of day.  If this works for me, I'll check it.  Upvoting regardless.

Comment: I still have some issues to resolve with my DBA, but I think this will work. tx

Answer (score 1):

Turn off autocommit

```
 conn = pyodbc.connect(
        r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server_name + '; \
        Database=' + db_name + ';Trusted_Connection=yes;', timeout=5, autocommit=False)
```

and commit here, and at the end of the loop.

```
    if index % 1000 == 0:
            print("Imported %s rows" % (index))
```

With autocommit you have to wait for the log file to save to disk after each row.

To optimize further, if you're on SQL 2016+ use JSON to send batches of rows to SQL Server, parsing on the server side with [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Changing the commit does not seem to alter the execution speed noticeably.  I'll take a look at the OPENJSON path.

Comment: Please add to the question your observed insert rate in rows/sec, and (if SQL 2016) the resuts of `select * from sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats where session_id = @@spid` run after the load.  Single row inserts with transaction batching should be 100's/sec for a SQL Server on the local area network. 1000's per second with JSON, and 10,000's/sec with a true bulk load.